# Case and IIF in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2012

How would I get the same result in `LINQ` in `ASP.Net` as following `SQL` queries are bellow

in case

```
select *, case 
        when 
            gender = 1 then 'Male' else 'Female' end 
        as gen from info
```

and in iif

```
select iif(gender = 1, 'Male', 'Female') as gen, * from info
```

I tried following using suggestion, but throwing an error

```
InfoDataContext db = new InfoDataContext();

            var data = from y in db.infos
                       db.infos.Select(i => new info{info = i, i.gender == 1 ? "Male" : "Female"}).ToList()
                       select y;

            GridView1.DataSource = data;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

one more is that, first query is returning the new result as last column in the table and second query as the first column in the table. How to re-arrange or replace `gen` column with `gender` column

Comment: Your LINQ is total mess because of that the error is thrown.

Comment: your end result must be- 

`var data = db.infos.Select(i => new {info = i, i.gender == 1 ? "Male" : "Female"}).ToList()`

Comment: still error exists. **invalid anonymous type member declared**

Answer (score 7):

Just use the ternary operator:

```
var data = context.info.Select(i => new {info = i, gender = i.gender == 1 ? "Male" : "Female"}).ToList();
```

Comment: ` InfoDataContext db = new InfoDataContext();

            var data = from y in db.infos
                       db.infos.Select(i => new info{info = i, i.gender == 1 ? "Male" : "Female"}).ToList()
                       select y;
                       
            GridView1.DataSource = data;
            GridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: @QadeerMangrio your syntax is wrong remove `new info{` and replace with just `new { info = i....`}

Comment: I edited the answer to make clear that you do not need any other select or so before assigning the result to your data variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with you suggestion.

```
InfoDataContext db = new InfoDataContext();
            var dat = db.infos.Select(i => new {info = i,i.id, i.name, Gen= i.gender == true ? "Male" : "Female", i.city});
            GridView1.DataSource = dat;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```